# intergrate magtek idynamo usaepay

Tags: java, ios, objective-c

Does any one had intergrate idynamo usa for ios app. I have just intergrated but got some problem. This is my code in IOS App:

```
 NSString *responseString = [(MTSCRA*)instance getResponseData];
    NSData *responseData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSString *encodedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"enc://%@", [responseData base64EncodedString]];
```

I send this encoding String to gate way.

This code, I have written in java server:

```
String magStrip="enc://JUU/OzU0ODU2NioqKioqKjM3NzQ9MTcxMCoqKioqKioqKioqKioqKio/fDA2MDB8JUU/fENGREY0RTZBRTFFMkJGNTFDMEU5M0VCRTFEQzY5NDcxQjUyMDk2QjJCRDVBQjIwQkY5N0U1N0E5Mzc3NUUxMzdBRTVGMDA5REJEMTI2REREfHw2MTQwMDIwMHwyRTNGRjNEQjdGRTRCQzU5QUY3OThCNDdEMTlDQjVDQkEzMEU5NDNCRjg2OTVFRkFBRURBNkNCRkUzMTRGN0ZGNUE5QTVBQjQyMzBFRkUzNEJBMEUxMDRCRjFDQjhGQTJEMEIzMThGNjkwMERCNUJCfEIzMzlBQzAwNDAxMTZBQXxBRUJERUQ0MTg2QUQxREI4fDkwMTE4ODBCMzM5QUMwMDAwMDIwfDI4OEN8fDAwMDA=";           card.setMagStripe(magStrip);            
params.setCreditCardData(card);             
RunSale request = new RunSale();            
request.setToken(token);            
request.setParams(params);          
com.usaepay.api.jaxws.TransactionResponse response;
response = client.runSale(token, params);
```

When I call in server, I retrive response :

> can not parse stripe mag.